# tkinter PhotoImage object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, tkinter, dynamic

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk    
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import ttk
import kalkulasi

#making the window
root = Tk()
root.title('Estimasi Perjalanan Kereta Rute Tangerang-Depok')
root.minsize(400,400)
root.geometry('650x700')

#define image
image = Image.open('petafix.png')

#define image as bg
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

# create canvas
main_canvas = Canvas(root, width=650, height=700)
main_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# set img in canvas
main_canvas.create_image(325, 300, image=bg)

# add "Selamat Datang!" text
main_canvas.create_text(325, 25, text="Selamat Datang!", font=('Helvetica', 25))



# making resize "HITUNG" button image
hitung_button = Image.open('button.jpg')
hitung_button_resized = hitung_button.resize((75, 30), Image.ANTIALIAS)
new_hitung_button = ImageTk.PhotoImage(hitung_button_resized)
label_hitung_button = Label(root, image= new_hitung_button, border= 0, anchor='center')
label_hitung_button.pack()

# reposition the "hitung" button
button = Button(root, image= new_hitung_button, border= 0, highlightthickness= 0,)
button_window = main_canvas.create_window(300, 670, anchor='nw', window=button)


# making resizer function
def resizer(event):
    global bg1, resized_bg, new_bg
    # open the image
    bg1 = Image.open('petafix.png)
    # Resize the image
    resized_bg = bg1.resize((event.width, event.height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    # define image again as new bg
    new_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_bg)
    # add new bg back to the canvas
    main_canvas.create_image(325, 300, image=new_bg)



root.bind('<Configure>', resizer)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to make my GUI window's dynamic, but there is an error i can't figured out that when i run the program, the program want to run but it still not dynamic and in the terminal, there is an error says AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'read'.

Comment: `bg1 = Image.open(bg)` doesn't make sense given that `bg` isn't a filename. Also in `resizer`, in the last line, it should be `image=new_bg` instead of `image=bg`

Comment: i've tried to change that bg in bg1, and change the image=bg to image=new_bg one but it still error

Comment: i've edited my code btw, thankss but it still error

Comment: Can you show the new error traceback? Without it, I can only guess other mistakes in your code.

Comment: wait, now, there is on error in the terminal but the resizer wont work

Comment: @toyotaSupra Why is that? `Image.open` can take relative paths as well.

Comment: i think, path is not the problem

Comment: It worked for me. When I move the window, the image is resized to larger. There are no errors so far. I am using Python 3.120b3